# Using absolute URLs with file-loader

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I have a project with a following structure:

```
/src/images/image.png
/src/modules/myModule/views/template.html
```

And I would like to reference `image.png` from `template.html` using `file-loader` but I don't want to use ugly relative URL, that could easily break:

```
<img src="../../../images/image.png">
```

Instead I would like to use an absolute URL:

```
<img src="/images/image.png">
```

Is there a `file-loader` settings that allows me to do that? Now the absolute URL seems completely ignored by the loader; URL does not change and browser is reporting 404 on `/images/image.png`. Relative URL above works fine.

Comment: have you tried this   <img src="./images/image.png">

Comment: It seems that urls will be absolute when you set `publicPath`: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath